# How do I display taxonomy content from taxonomy category?

Tags: theming

I have fields in taxonomy under category taxonomy. Attempted views but couldn't find taxonomy fields to add as fields :(

Do not want node fields.

What I did is:
1. Create taxonomy, category
2. Add terms, dog, cat, etc
3. Add fields such as image, description, etc

So on view, all terms under category taxonomies appear in a view with description, images and more.

How do I display all taxonomy terms' content under category?

**Updated**

[image]

Vocabulary: Categories
Taxonomy: Body Contouring for example. 
Inside, it has the description and image.

So wanted to list taxonomies with their details in grid layout. Attempted views, but it is only all content type related to taxonomies' id.

I only need content from taxonomies. How do I display taxonomies' content?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of your full requirements as it is a bit confusing but it sounds like you are trying to output all the fields of a specific Taxonomy.

If you are using Drupal 7, just create a view of 'Show' Taxonomy Terms.

Then from there add the taxonomy fields that you require by searching from the 'add field' dropdown.

Finally create a filter for taxonomy term 'category'.

Hopefully that is what you are after.

[image]

Do you not see this filter when creating your view. What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I am trying to show all fields of all taxonomies under Categories. I do not see 'show' taxonomy terms on view. That's why i was puzzled.

Comment: updated: nope i couldn't add taxonomy field not node field. where to find taxonomy field :(

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: In views, you first set up a relationship to your taxonomy (under advanced). You can then use fields and filters from related taxonomy. Here's how:

1. Create a view of your content.
2. Under Advanced->Relationship, click Add, then choose the taxonomy field (Content:field-name)

[image: Add relationship]

[image: Configure relationship as needed]

3. Under fields, find "Taxonomy Term:" items. Here you can add individual fields with a relationship to your term.

[image: These fields will now pop up in your view]

Option 2: install display suite module, define a custom view mode and use this view mode in views. Here's how:

1. Install Display Suite.
2. Create a custom view mode for a taxonomy and set it up as you want it to appear:

[image: Create a custom view mode]

[image: Set up a custom taxonomy view mode as you see fit]

3. Repeat for the node, but this time use the new view mode to render the taxonomy in the node.

[image: Set up a custom node view with taxonomy rendered in our view mode]

4. Set up a view, but this time instead of fields, choose to output full content and select the correct view mode.

[image: Finally, choose the correct view mode for the view]

Now if you ever choose to change how your taxonomy or your node are displayed, the view will automatically adapt to the changes. You may not see it with one view, but trust me, when you have dozens of views and thousands of products, those view modes are life-savers, so you may as well do it right from the start.

Comment: I checked view mode then check taxonomy. but where to put view mode in view?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I've edited my comment to explain how either is done.